# unique key storing more duplicate nulls

Tags: mysql

As per my knowledge, unique key stores only one null. But in this case, it accepts more null.I don't know why?

This what exactly happens

[image]

Comment: Super mega broad question. And you can find the info on the internet easily.

Comment: Correct your knowledge then: _For all engines, a UNIQUE index permits multiple NULL values for columns that can contain NULL ([ref](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html)). MySQL <> MSSQL.

Answer (score 0):

No, Unique key stores multiple null.

**Oracle**:

[Oracle Thread](https://community.oracle.com/thread/376915?tstart=0)

**MySql**:

> A UNIQUE index creates a constraint such that all values in the index
>   must be distinct. An error occurs if you try to add a new row with a
>   key value that matches an existing row. For all engines, a UNIQUE
>   index allows multiple NULL values for columns that can contain NULL.

[MySql Thread](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html)

Comment: This question if for mysql.